# Does React allow getting or setting props outside of components

Tags: reactjs

When I have a component inside a component

```
var MySubComponent;

class MyComponent {
...
getChildProps() {
console.log(MySubComponent.props.nameToGet)
}
...
MySubComponent = withCustomAudio(props => {return(<div>...</div>)});
...
render() {
return(...<MySubComponent {...this.props}/>...)
}
...}
```

After component render I'd like to get or set the prop of the subcomponent. It returns `cant access nameToGet of undefined`

Spread attributes is not what I want
 (https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example with valid javascript code? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't be able to get/set props like this. It's not the React way. You should read more about [thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Basically, if you want to change `child` props in the `parent`, they should be part of the `parent` state and passed down to the child as props.

Example:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    childProp: "Not changed yet"
  }
  handleChildPropChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      childProp: "I changed"
    }) 
  }
  render() {
    return <Child myProp={this.state.childProp} onChangeChildProp={this.handleChildPropChange} />;
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={onChangeChildProp}>{this.props.myProp}</div>
    )
  }
}
```